# Why does HK2 repackage everything?

Tags: java, maven, dependency-management, jersey-2.0, hk2

I've recently switched from Jersey 1 to Jersey 2 for some projects I work on. The biggest annoyance I've run across with Jersey 2 is that it uses HK2, which for some reason repackages standard Maven artifacts.  To avoid potential annoying-to-debug issues, I try to avoid pulling in the same classes from different projects.  I use the [Ban Duplicate Classes](https://www.mojohaus.org/extra-enforcer-rules/banDuplicateClasses.html) Maven enforcer rules from the Extra Enforcer Rules dependency to break the build if this occurs.

According to the aforementioned Ban Duplicate Classes enforcer rule, switching to Jersey 2 has introduced the following conflicts between its artifacts and standard ones I was previously using:

```
hk2 Artifact                                                Conflicting Artifact
org.glassfish.hk2.external:aopalliance-repackaged:2.3.0-b07 aopalliance:aopalliance:1.0
org.glassfish.hk2.external:bean-validator:2.3.0-b07         com.fasterxml:classmate:0.8.0 (used by org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:5.0.0.Final)
org.glassfish.hk2.external:bean-validator:2.3.0-b07         javax.validation:validation-api:1.1.0.Final
org.glassfish.hk2.external:bean-validator:2.3.0-b07         org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:5.0.0.Final
org.glassfish.hk2.external:bean-validator:2.3.0-b07         org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:3.1.0.GA
org.glassfish.hk2.external:javax.inject:2.3.0-b07           javax.inject:javax.inject:1
```

My solution has been to exclude the standard artifacts from the dependencies that transitively pull them, and therefore use only the hk2 artifacts. I figure this is safer: I don't know what else the hk2 artifacts are pulling in that I might be missing if I were to exclude them instead (for example, the bean-validator artifact appears to be repackaging at least four artifacts).  The  downsides to this are that first, I a ton of exclusions peppering my dependencies that were bringing in otherwise innocuous API dependencies, such as validation-api.  Secondly, my artifacts are now exporting HK2 repackaged dependencies, rather than the actual API classes I would prefer to be exporting.

Ultimately, my questions are:

1. Why does HK2 repackage everything?  Is there some good reason for this?
2. What is HK2 actually repackaging, and can I just use the standard API versions instead? How would I figure this out? I've cloned the HK2 project, and I've had a bit of trouble figuring out where to begin to find this out.

Barring the actual answer to these questions, what would be a good forum for contacting the developers behind HK2 so I can ask the question directly?  I've looked through the website, and while I've found some mailing lists, I'm not seeing anything obviously appropriate for asking this question.

Comment: Just ask the HK2 people to answer this question. Neither I don't understand such attitude.

Comment: As I stated in my question, part of my problem is that I couldn't find a good forum for asking the HK2 people directly.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

HK2 runs in an OSGi environment for products such as GlassFish.  Unfortunately most of the standard jars such as javax.inject, bean-validator and aopalliance do not come with proper OSGi headers.  So hk2 needs to repackage them with OSGi headers so that they will work properly in that environment.

Also since GlassFish is the RI for Java EE there are certain legal requirements that are made about the availability of the source code, so some of the repackaging that is done is to satisfy the availability of source code requirements.

That being said, if you are NOT running in an OSGi environment it is safe to replace these jars with the standard versions (though I myself have not tried this)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. For something like org.glassfish.hk2.external:bean-validator that appears to be duplicating multiple artifacts, how would I find out what artifacts this is replacing?  Is it adding any additional functionality beyond the various API artifacts that it appears to be duplicating?

I'm thinking I may be best off accepting that it will be duplicating stuff from standard API artifacts, and just adding some enforcer exclusion rules to ignore the duplication between hk2 and the standard APIs.

Comment: @M.Justin Best to look at the source, [bean-validator](https://github.com/hk2-project/hk2/tree/master/external/bean-validator) is just a (well documented) pom.xml. The interesting parts are probably in `<Embed-Dependency>` which defines the dependencies that will be repackaged.

Comment: @kapep Thanks; I didn't notice that.  The source itself mostly spells out what is being repackaged, though a few of them defined in the Private-Package section (classmate, jboss-logging) aren't explicitly called out in the POM (they're just matched by package name).

Comment: @kapex The link to bean-validator pom is broken, the new one is https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/glassfish/hk2/external/bean-validator/2.3.0/bean-validator-2.3.0.pom